# Measure the strings similarities by transposition

Tags: string, algorithm, similarity, levenshtein-distance

If I have three strings, the first one is `string1 = Laptop`, the second one is `string2 = Latpop` and the third one is `string3 = Lavmop`, then the levenshtein distance algorithm will return the same distance for the similarities of `string1`and `string2` and the similarities of `string1` and `string3`. that is because the levenshtein algorithm calculate only the operations: insert, delete and substution, which is not including the transposition operation, for example, we can swap the third and forth character at `Latpop` string which yields `Laptop`.

It's obviouse that `Latpop` is more similar to the `Laptop`  than `Lavmop`, and it's not correct to classify them in the same similarity level.

Is there an algorithm, that take into account the transposition operation?

Comment: Are you looking for something like: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing

Comment: I think what you are looking for is Damerau–Levenshtein distance . In addition to the operations in Levenshtein distance , this accounts for the additional operation of swapping **adjacent** characters 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in [Damerau–Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance) and [Jaro–Winkler distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaro%E2%80%93Winkler_distance)